# converting run.bat to run.sh

Tags: batch-file, sh

First of all i want to let you know i am searching my ass off for weeks now in my spare time and i still can't figure it out..

i have a run.bat that i want to run but i need to run it in linux mint 15 kde so it has to be a run.sh

Can some of you please look at it and maybe help me out with changing it i am desperate..

```
@echo off
title RSPS
cd src
cd ..
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java" -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -classpath bin;lib/* Main.Launcher
pause
```

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` set correctly on the machine? that would make it easier (and you probably should have been using that on Windows as well).

Answer (score 0):

Appendix N. Converting DOS Batch Files to Shell Scripts

Quite a number of programmers learned scripting on a PC running DOS. Even the crippled DOS batch file language allowed writing some fairly powerful scripts and applications, though they often required extensive kludges and workarounds. Occasionally, the need still arises to convert an old DOS batch file to a UNIX shell script. This is generally not difficult, as DOS batch file operators are only a limited subset of the equivalent shell scripting ones.
[more..](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html)

Comment: No reference to Java, so not sure how this answers the whole question.

Comment: Thanks! verry helpfull